# Creating Long & Lat for Polygons

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon

I have a base map image with micro regions, however in the attribute table there is no information regarding the long & lat. Is there a way I can create a long & lat for each micro region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ArcGIS 10.x you can 'calculate geometry' by going to the attribute table and right-clicking the field name.  With polygon layers, you can calculate the x coordinate and y coordinate of the polygon's centroid by clicking next to Property.  If you haven't already done so, you'll need to first add a new x_coord and y_coord field to the attribute table to hold the coordinate values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing based on the label that you're using ArcGIS 10.
There's a "Calculate Geometry" feature which will allow you to do this. [Full details and instructions here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000027000000) - Oh, and be sure to use either a Float or Double data type on the column you're going to put your lat/long into.

This will get you the centroid of the micro-regions.